# When I used Tab key Horizontal Scroll issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used tab key for entering values,alignment is missed and scroll not moved[image]I used Tables with Fixed Headers and Horizontal scrolling working fine but when I used tab key for entering data horizontal scroll is not moving, table cells alignment is missed

```js
$('.pane-hintervinientes').scroll(function() {
           $('.pane-vintervinientes').width($('.pane-hintervinientes').width() + $('.pane-hintervinientes').scrollLeft());
         });
```

```html
<div style="width: 750px !important;">
 
   
      <div class="pane pane--table1">
      <div class="pane-hintervinientes theadscroll" style="margin-left:12px;">

    <table class="scrolltable">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
        <th>Número de Documento</th>
        <th>Nombre o Razón Social</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Relación</th>
        <th>Fecha de Nacimiento/Fecha de Inicio de Actividades</th>
        <th>Agregar O Eliminar</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="pane-vintervinientes tbodyscroll">
      <table class="scrolltable">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             
        <td>      
       <div>    
                      <select class="form-control" style="padding: 1px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
       <option>1</option>          
         </select>
     </div>    
      </td>
        
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;width: 80%"><input type="button" value="Lr" class="buttonsinline LrButton">
        </td>     
        
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
          
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
              
           <td>      
       <div>    
                      <select class="form-control" style="padding: 1px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
       <option>1</option>          
         </select>
     </div>    
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;width: 81%;"  id="datepicker1" >
        </td>
      <td>

         <div><input type="button" value="+" style="width:20px;margin-left:35px">
                     <input type="button" value="-" style="width:20px;margin-left:10px"></div>
                  </td>
        
       </tr>
       
      
     </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

```js
 $('.pane-hintervinientes').scroll(function() {
   $('.pane-vintervinientes').width($('.pane-hintervinientes').width() + $('.pane-hintervinientes').scrollLeft());
 });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 14px/1 Arial, sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pane {
  background: #eee;
}
.pane-hScroll {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}
.pane-vScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.pane--table2 {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.pane--table2 th, .pane--table2 td {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 160px;
}
.pane--table2 tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
.pane--table2 thead {
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 750px !important;">
 
   
      <div class="pane pane--table1">
      <div class="pane-hintervinientes theadscroll" style="margin-left:12px;">

    <table class="scrolltable">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Tipo de Documento</th>
        <th>Número de Documento</th>
        <th>Nombre o Razón Social</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Relación</th>
        <th>Fecha de Nacimiento/Fecha de Inicio de Actividades</th>
        <th>Agregar O Eliminar</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="pane-vintervinientes tbodyscroll">
      <table class="scrolltable">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             
        <td>      
       <div>    
                      <select class="form-control" style="padding: 1px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
       <option>1</option>          
         </select>
     </div>    
      </td>
        
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;width: 80%"><input type="button" value="Lr" class="buttonsinline LrButton">
        </td>     
        
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
          
        <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;">
        </td>
              
           <td>      
       <div>    
                      <select class="form-control" style="padding: 1px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#">
       <option>1</option>          
         </select>
     </div>    
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="inputselectwidth" style="height: 20px;width: 81%;"  id="datepicker1" >
        </td>
      <td>

         <div><input type="button" value="+" style="width:20px;margin-left:35px">
                     <input type="button" value="-" style="width:20px;margin-left:10px"></div>
                  </td>
        
       </tr>
       
      
     </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Alignment is good and move the hotizental scrool bar

[image: Without Tab alignmet is good]

Comment: you say that when using TAB key to move from one input not another, the scroll doesn't 'move' ? i cannot replicate that : https://jsfiddle.net/b39g0wkf/

Comment: https://codepen.io/springborg/pen/MvPmPP check this one

Comment: in that example you don't have any form elements. ( input/button/select etc. ) . So ofcourse tab won't work.  `when I used tab key for entering data` where are you entering that data if you don't have any inputs for eg ?

Comment: above url put input for first table and check once

Answer (score 1):

The frozen columns functionality is implemented by hiding the RadGrid "real" scrollbar (used with the scrolling with static headers) and using a "fake" one, which triggers some columns to be hidden and shown, depending on the scrollbar position. However, when you start tabbing through the textboxes, you are beggining to scroll the complete RadGrid data area, including the frozen columns. In other words, this is the same as scrolling the "real" hidden scrollbar. This is the cause tabbing and frozen scrolling to be not supported.

However, there is a workaround which works in a few scenarios. You should keep in mind that this is a custom code which is not universal and it will not work in all scenarios:
but it can help you this is example function

```
function OnGridCreated(sender, args)
{
    var frozenScroll = $get(sender.get_id() + "_Frozen");
    var allColumns = sender.get_masterTableView().get_columns();
    var scrollLeftOffset = 0;
    var allColumnsWidth = new Array;
    var grid = sender.get_element();
    for (var i = 0; i < allColumns.length; i++)
    {
        allColumnsWidth[i] = allColumns[i].get_element().offsetWidth;
    }

    $get(sender.get_id() + "_GridData").onscroll = function (e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < allColumns.length; i++)
        {
            if (!allColumns[i].get_visible())
            {
                scrollLeftOffset += allColumnsWidth[i];
            }
            if ($telerik.isIE7)
            {
                var thisColumn = grid.getElementsByTagName("colgroup")[0].getElementsByTagName("col")[i];
                if (thisColumn.style.display == "none")
                {
                    scrollLeftOffset += parseInt(thisColumn.style.width);
                }
            }
        }
        var thisScrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
        if (thisScrollLeft > 0)
            frozenScroll.scrollLeft = thisScrollLeft + scrollLeftOffset + 300;
        this.scrollLeft = 0;
        scrollLeftOffset = 0;
    }
}
```